# How to draw different sets of contours over 3d surfaces with plotly?

Tags: 3d, plotly, contour, surface

I would like to draw 2 different sets of contours lines over a 3D surface using plotly. So far I can only get 1 set at a time, namely, the one from the last call to 'fig.update_traces' below. How could I get both sets drawn? By the way, I understand the logic behind an "update_traces", i.e., it is designed to enforce only the last call, but theres seems to be no "add_trace(contours_z)" call in plotly that can do the same job as "update_traces(contours_z)"...

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
# data 
xx = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
yy = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xx,yy) 
Z = 10*np.exp(-(X*X+Y*Y))
# plot
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(x=X,y=Y,z=Z)) 
fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True,color='red' ,start=0,end=5,size=1))
fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True,color='blue',start=6,end=10,size=1))
fig.show()
```